# download and add resources eg.layouts, drawables dynamically to app in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-resources

Here is the thing,
I want to download resources from the Internet and add them to my application.However, I have searched a lot and did not get a solution.So, Finally asking you guys, Please help!!!!

Findings:

1. I can load java code with dexClassLoader.
2. I can not not use APK extension file.
3. I dont want to access resources from another APK. Because then I need to ask user to install one more apk.
4. If I download resources just like an image file and try to use bitmap,Will it be too slow for my app.

Please do not say "NO its not possible".Will any hack do this???

Comment: for dynamic layouts try this https://github.com/zserge/anvil

Answer (score 1):

> I want to download resources from the Internet and add them to my application

You are certainly welcome to download files and use them. You cannot download *resources* as defined by the Android SDK, as those have to be compiled into the app.

> I can load java code with dexClassLoader.

This has security ramifications. I do not recommend this.

> If I download resources just like an image file and try to use bitmap,Will it be too slow for my app.

Many Android apps download images from the Internet.